# How to select multiple values for one table "cell" MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

For all players, I need to find the player number and a list of the numbers of teams for which they have ever played.

Here is the table "MATCHES":

```
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------+
| MATCHNO | TEAMNO | PLAYERNO | WON | LOST |
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------+
|       1 |      1 |        6 |   3 |    1 |
|       2 |      1 |        6 |   2 |    3 |
|       3 |      1 |        6 |   3 |    0 |
|       4 |      1 |       44 |   3 |    2 |
|       5 |      1 |       83 |   0 |    3 |
|       6 |      1 |        2 |   1 |    3 |
|       7 |      1 |       57 |   3 |    0 |
|       8 |      1 |        8 |   0 |    3 |
|       9 |      2 |       27 |   3 |    2 |
|      10 |      2 |      104 |   3 |    2 |
|      11 |      2 |      112 |   2 |    3 |
|      12 |      2 |      112 |   1 |    3 |
|      13 |      2 |        8 |   0 |    3 |
+---------+--------+----------+-----+------+
```

The best I could come up with was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerno, teamno
FROM matches
ORDER BY playerno;
```

which results in:

```
+----------+--------+
| playerno | teamno |
+----------+--------+
|        2 |      1 |
|        6 |      1 |
|        8 |      1 |
|        8 |      2 |
|       27 |      2 |
|       44 |      1 |
|       57 |      1 |
|       83 |      1 |
|      104 |      2 |
|      112 |      2 |
+----------+--------+
```

Notice how player 8 has played on two teams. How can I get the table to show only one row for player 8 and a list of teamno's (1 & 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT   playerno, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teamno)
FROM     matches
GROUP BY playerno
ORDER BY playerno;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use group_concat

```
SELECT playerno, group_concat( teamno)
FROM matches
GROUP BY playerno;
```